# unrecognized import path "google/protobuf"

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm trying to setup chaincode environment and start learning to develop chaincode, I followed the setup steps [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/devenv.md) and tested my setup environment as mentioned [here](https://golang.org/doc/install#testing)
When I'm trying to add the Hyperledger shim to my environment (as explained [here](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/learn-chaincode) ), I'm getting the following error : 
`package google/protobuf: unrecognized import path "google/protobuf"`

I've protobuf installed. The `protoc --version` command gives me `libprotoc 2.6.1` as output. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: What version of Go are you using?

Comment: I'm using go1.5.3 darwin

Comment: Upgrade to go1.6.2

Comment: well, Thanks a lot that worked like charms. I don't understand because this was working earlier for the older verison of go.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `google/protobuf` is in a vendor directory, and `vendor/` is only searched for imports by default starting in go1.6, (and optionally in go1.5 with GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT, but you should be on at least go1.6 anyway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The instructions for establishing a development environment that were [cited](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/docs/dev-setup/devenv.md) in the original question are pretty clear that Go 1.6 or above is a [prerequisite](https://github.com/christo4ferris/fabric/blob/issue-2144/docs/dev-setup/devenv.md#prerequisites). Upgrading to 1.6.2, per @jimb comment above resolved the issue.